# Laplace Transform and Inverse laplace Transform for 2D images python code available?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, laplace-transform, discrete-wavelet-transform

I am wondering if there is any implementation of Laplace Transform and Inverse Laplace Transform available for 2D data (i.e., images). For example, a batch of `N` input sequence of `D` can be reshaped into a 2D image with width of `W` and height of `H` and then 2D FFT is applied in both directions and then after processing it in the frequency domain, will be transformed back to the spatial domain using Inverse FFT, the `pytorch deep learning library` had the functions as follows:

```
# x: (B x N x D)  the token features, B x H x W x D (where N = H * W), B: batch size
# K: the frequency-domain filter, H x W_hat x D (where W_hat = W // 2 + 1)
X = rfft2(x, dim=(1, 2))
X_tilde = X * K
x = irfft2(X_tilde, dim=(1, 2))
```

Is there any similar implementation for Laplace Transform in Python?

Comment: The Laplace Transform is for continuous-"time" (in your case, continuous-position) to continuous-frequency on the complex plane.  Now, once you start sampling in time (or sampling in position) it becomes the Z Transform.  Now do you want to compute the two-dimensional Z transform of a pixelated image?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks for your reply, I am very new to this field. Regarding your question, I am trying to convert the image from Euclidean spatial domain and obtain `the Laplace Transform`, process the laplace transformed data, and then return it back to the spatial domain. Also, is there any link/code that can help to understand? Or is there any way to obtain the Laplace Transform using FFT? Thanks again

Comment: @S.EB The FFT will give you  the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of your data. The relationship between  the DFT and the Z- transform is similar to that one of the Continuous Fourier Transform and the Laplace Transform. If you are not aware of the differences between these transforms I strongly suggest spending some time with a good text book. It's rather complicated and although it's all somewhat similar there are subtle differences that can make big differences in outcome.

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks for the comment, can you introduce some references for base studies?